# Magento 1 Random review generator

Tags: magento-1.9, review, programmatically, sample-data

I have a site running Magento 1.9.3 and I want to generate random reviews.
I don't need the content to be using target keywords or anything - I only need it for testing different layouts and design concepts.
Is there a tool or a script out there that can help me get this done?